# How to configure yii2-solr extension

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, solarium

I want to use [yii2-solr](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-solr#add-comment) extension in one of my projects. How can I configure this extension. Nothing is mentioned on the extension page. Has anyone used this extension? Any help would be appreciable. Thank you.

I found the extension on [github repo](https://github.com/Sammaye/yii2-solr) . In readme file it is mention to configure it as follows:

```
'solr' => [
        'class' => 'sammaye\solr\Client',
        'options' => [
            'endpoint' => [
                'solr1' => [
                    'host' => '10.208.225.66',
                    'port' => '8983',
                    'path' => '/solr'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

But after doing all this I am getting the following error:

```
Class 'Solarium\Client' not found
```

In one of its Client.php file the line is:

```
use Solarium\Client as SolrClient;
```

I checked all the files but Solarium namespace is not there.

Comment: Did you look at [GitHub repository README](https://github.com/Sammaye/yii2-solr)?

Comment: Yes @arogachev I read the Readme file and configured the extension but I am getting error. I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

yii2-solr depends on the Solarium library. If you installed yii2-solr via composer, it should have automatically downloaded it as dependency. Check github [composer.json](https://github.com/Sammaye/yii2-solr/blob/master/composer.json#L13). If not, you'll have to install it manually, see [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/solarium/solarium).

Comment: There is no reason to install it manually because it's in extension dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I reinstalled the extension and now it seems to be working:)